# Transition from a core framework

Tags: javascript, rest, architecture, frameworks, wicket

I wish all of you a happy new year.

I'm new in a project that relies on Apache Wicket which is not exactly known for having a big user base these days. In fact, it makes it hard for us to find new people and we would like to transition to a newer framework eventually. Unfortunately, the codebase is just too big to "simply" rewrite the whole damn thing.

What I wanted to ask is the following:
Does anyone have a viable strategy for transitioning from a framework like Wicket to a more "modern" REST-Interface + JS-Webframework approach? I would think that it should be possible to use the existing API that Wicket must be exposing for its own frontend for whatever js framework we'd be choosing to later down the road create the whole frontend.

Any ideas?

Comment: We have the same problem and we don't have a clear strategy so far. I know that with Wicket Rest resources (from wicketstuff) we can use incorporate pure Javascript components, but we don't have clear map ahead of how we should migrate our apps. I agree, Wicket appears dead nowadays.

Comment: It is also not Wicket's fault - just that the JS frameworks are very superior to it.,

Answer (score 2):

I have integrated a few Javascript pure components with Wicket - the main thing you need to figure out is how to make them talk - in Wicket, you can use a RestResource that is mounted in your application to server JSON content.

For example:

```
class LayoutToolRestResource() : AbstractRestResource<JacksonWebSerializer>(JacksonWebSerializer()) {
  @SpringBean
  internal lateinit var layoutObjectTreeSupplier: LayoutObjectTreeSupplier

  /**
   * Reads the tree nodes from the given data source.
   * Example: http://localhost:8080/layout-api/tree-nodes?dataSourceName=admuser1625
   */
  @MethodMapping("/tree-nodes")
  fun objectTreeNodes(@RequestParam(value = "dataSourceName") dataSourceName: String?): List<TreeNode> {
    requireNotNull(dataSourceName) { "You must select a source data-source" }
    return layoutObjectTreeSupplier.buildTreeNodeList(dataSourceName)
  }
}
```

This is Kotlin code. The library is Wicket Stuff - https://wicketstuff.org/.

You mount this resource in your application:

```
    mountResource(
        "/layout-api",
        new ResourceReference( "layout-api" )
        {
            @Override
            public IResource getResource()
            {
                return LoaderWebApplication.this.layoutApiResource;
            }
        }
    );
```

In the Javascript application, you refer to the resource to get the JSON data you need:

```
function getData(dataSourceName) {
  var contextPathField = document.getElementsByName('contextPath')[0];
  var url = contextPathField.textContent + "/layout-api/tree-nodes?dataSourceName=" + dataSourceName;
  wijmo.httpRequest(url, {
      success: function (xhr) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        wijmoTree.itemsSource = data;
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
        // do something here
        var errorData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(errorData.errorMessage);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

This way you can integrate applications that work with JSON data (most of the web frameworks do) with Wicket. You can have pages that use this type of approach and pages that use the "classic" approach, or use more modern components in your page that retrieve the data like this.

Hope this helps.